# How to write to a file with newline characters and avoid empty lines

Tags: python, file, newline

I'm trying to write encoded data to a file and separate each run with a newline character. However, when doing this there is an empty line between each run -- as shown below.

Using .rstrip()/.strip() only really works when reading the file -- and obviously this cannot be used directly when writing to the file as it would write all the data to a single line.

```
cFile = open('compFile', 'w')
for i in range(num_lines):
    line = validLine()
    compressedFile.write(line + "\n")
cFile.close()

cFile = open('compFile', 'r')
for line in cFile:
    print(line)


# Empty space output:

023

034

045

# Desired output:

023
034
045
```

Comment: String stripping works *at any point you have a string*. Just add the newline when writing *after* stripping.

Answer (score 2):

I think you already did what you want if you have a look at your text file.

Be aware, that python reads the \n at the end of your file too and that print() makes a newline at the end of the printed line.

In your case that means your file should look like

> 023\n
>
> 034\n
>
> 045\n

When printing, you at first read 023\n and then as python does with the print() function you append a \n to your line.

Then you have the 023\n\n you get in your console. But in the file you have what you want.

If you just want to print without linebreak, you can use

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write('.')
```

Comment: You can also print without line break using print(text, end=""). The default value of end is a line break.

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
for i in range(num_lines):
    line = validLine()
    compressedFile.write(line.strip() + "\n")
    #                          ^^^   
cFile.close()
```

Off-topic but consider using `with ()` additionally.

Answer (score 0):

> Using .rstrip()/.strip() only really works when reading the file -- and obviously this cannot be used directly when writing to the file as it would write all the data to a single line.

This is a misconception. Using `.rstrip()` is exactly the correct tool if you need to write a series of strings, *some* of which may have a newline character attached:

```
with open('compFile', 'w') as cFile:
    for i in range(num_lines):
        line = validLine().rstrip("\n") # remove possible newline
        compressedFile.write(line + "\n")
```

Note that if **all your lines already have a newline attached**, you don't have to add more newlines. Just write the string directly to the file, no stripping needed:

```
with open('compFile', 'w') as cFile:
    for i in range(num_lines):
        line = validLine()  # line with "\n" newline already present
        compressedFile.write(line)  # no need to add a newline anymore
```

Next, you are reading lines *with newlines* from your file and then printing them with `print()`. By default, `print()` **adds another newline**, so you end up with double-spaced lines; your input file contains `023\n034\n045\n`, but printing each line (`'023\n'`, then `'034\n'`, then `'045\n'`) adds a newline afterwards and you write out `023\n\n034\n\n045\n\n` out to `stdout`.

Either strip that newline when printing, or tell `print()` to not add a newline of its own by giving it an empty `end` parameter:

```
with open('compFile', 'r') as cFile: 
    for line in cFile:
        print(line, end='')
```